# Flexbox: scrollable content with sticky footer

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a box (flex-item in this case) which always stays in the middle of it's container. In that box, there is a header, footer and content section. If the size of the content grows too big in height, I want the content section to be scrollable. The header and footer should always be visible and the box should always stay in it's container.

Here is what I have been able to write:

HTML

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
     <header>Header</header>
     <div class="content">
        A
      <br>B
      <br>C
      <br>D
      <br>E
      <br>F
      <br>G
      <br>H
      <br>I
      <br>J
      <br>K
     </div>
     <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 120px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; /* We can assume that the container's height is hardcoded in this example, but the end solution should work even if this value is changed*/
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  /* It should be possible to scroll this element when it get too big in height*/
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}
```

The code is hosted on JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9fduhpev/3/

To explain the same thing visually, here is the current situation:
[image: Problem]

Here is what I want:

[image: How it should work]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `overflow-y: auto;`.

Read this: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp

```css
body {
  margin: 120px;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.content {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
     <header>Header</header>
     <div class="content">
        A
      <br>B
      <br>C
      <br>D
      <br>E
      <br>F
      <br>G
      <br>H
      <br>I
      <br>J
      <br>K
      <br>L
     </div>
     <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: In fact I think I'm going to use overflow-y: auto to show the scrollbar only when the content gets too big. At least on Windows the "scroll" value makes the scrollbar always visible, which is something that I don't want.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you give it `overflow: auto`. With that it will be scrollable when needed.

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  justify-content: center;
}
.flex-item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 150px;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  align-self: center;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  max-height: 100%;
}
.content {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
     <header>Header</header>
     <div class="content">
        A
      <br>B
      <br>C
      <br>D
      <br>E
      <br>F
      <br>G
      <br>H
      <br>I
      <br>J
      <br>K
      <br>L
     </div>
     <footer>Footer</footer>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
.content {
  height: 100%;
  overflow:auto;
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9fduhpev/4/